# Applying same code over several .csv files

Tags: r

I have several .csv files in the same format of pumping volumes every minute. I need to aggregate the total pumping volumes for each day. Some of the data have text errors (data logger off) or negative values (means flow was 0). I wrote the below code to do this. How can I loop this over several files instead of copying and pasting for each month? All files are labeled "Mon_Year_Well_Flows.csv". I tried using a for loop and using lapply with no success. Also, I am very new to R so I understand my code is likely very inefficient.

First lines of first month data file "Jul_2017_Well_Flows.csv"

```
Date        DW_20   DW_24A  DW_25A   DW_26A DW_27A  DW_28   DW_29
9/1/18 0:00 995.88  1110.62 1229.14  -0.09  4.5    1100.95  913.33
9/1/18 0:01 1002.43 1115.85 1231.59  -0.09  4.5    1107.63  909.06
9/1/18 0:02 1007.01 1123.39 1236.75  -0.09  4.51   1108.37  935
9/1/18 0:03 1007.17 1121.69 1234.58  -0.09  4.52   1105.64  901.35
9/1/18 0:04 1005.27 1122.86 1233.25  -0.09  4.53   1107.56  911.15
9/1/18 0:05 1001.37 1116.39 1229.89  -0.09  4.54   1103.66  937.93
```

Code for first month data file

```
#Load data
data <- read.csv("Jul_2017_Well_Flows.csv", header = T)
#Create new data frame with date info
data1 <- data.frame("Date" = data$Date)
#Remove all error text to NA
index <- supply(data, is.factor)
data[index] <- apply(data[index], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
#Convert all NA values to 0
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
#Converting all negative pumping rates to 0
data[,-c(1)][data[,-c(1)]<0] <-0
#Add back original date column
data <- select(data, -Date)
data <- bind_cols(data,data1)
#Remove minute data and change day to date formatting
data$Day <- as.Date(data$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
Jul_2017 <- data %>%
  #Remove date column
  select(-Date) %>%
  #Group all data according to day
  group_by(day) %>%
  #Sum all daily well data by day
  summarize_all(sum)
```

At the end of copying and pasting above code for each month I do the following to bind all of the output files together-

```
combined <- bind_rows(Jul_2017, Aug_2017....)
```

Comment: The first thing to do you be to fix the obvious errors in that code. (Wrong format date string and misspelled column names.) You should run the code in a fresh session before posting questions. Also as written and illustrated there would be separate data and time coluuns. I suspect your file actually has commas if that is what it looks like after import.

Comment: 1) Put your code into a function, say `sumOneFile` that takes the file name as an argument, and returns the result. 2) test your function with a single file name with something like `result <- sumOneFile("Jul_2017_Well_Flows.csv")` 3) Then use something like `combined <- bind_rows(lapply(c("file1.csv", "file2.csv"), sumOneFile)` 4) look at `list.files` function to get a list from the directory

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer this question:

> > How can I loop this over several files instead of copying and pasting for each month?

To get your started, one method is to first get the list of filenames in that directory. Try:

```
filenames <- list.files("temp", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)


#Load data
data <- read.csv(filenames[[1]], header = T) # read in the first file as usual


#Create new data frame with date info
data1 <- data.frame("Date" = data$Date)
#Remove all error text to NA
index <- supply(data, is.factor)
data[index] <- apply(data[index], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
#Convert all NA values to 0
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
#Converting all negative pumping rates to 0
data[,-c(1)][data[,-c(1)]<0] <-0
#Add back original date column
data <- select(data, -Date)
data <- bind_cols(data,data1)
#Remove minute data and change day to date formatting
data$Day <- as.Date(data$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
Jul_2017 <- data %>%
  #Remove date column
  select(-Date) %>%
  #Group all data according to day
  group_by(day) %>%
  #Sum all daily well data by day
  summarize_all(sum)


#I'm not sure if you can use bind_rows with one argument - I am not able
# to test code at the moment. Create a storage place for the combined dfs.
combined <- bind_rows(Jul_2017)

for (i in 2:len(filenames)) {
temp_month <- read.csv(filenames[[i]], header = TRUE) # Notice the temp_month

#Load data
data <- read.csv(filenames[[1]], header = T) # read in first file as usual
#Create new data frame with date info
data1 <- data.frame("Date" = data$Date)
#Remove all error text to NA
index <- supply(data, is.factor)
data[index] <- apply(data[index], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
#Convert all NA values to 0
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
#Converting all negative pumping rates to 0
data[,-c(1)][data[,-c(1)]<0] <-0
#Add back original date column
data <- select(data, -Date)
data <- bind_cols(data,data1)
#Remove minute data and change day to date formatting
data$Day <- as.Date(data$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
temp_month <- data %>%
  #Remove date column
  select(-Date) %>%
  #Group all data according to day
  group_by(day) %>%
  #Sum all daily well data by day
  summarize_all(sum)

combined <- bind_rows(combined, temp_month)
}
```

Comment: `list.files()` returns a vector, not a list. So `[[]]` won't work. Building the object  `combined` up in this way (adding new data every iteration) is not very effective. Not calling the setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv()` creates the Date column as factor which means a lot of the other code won't work. Just a few hints :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to change your code a bit as there were several errors in it.

One easy way is to first write a function consisting of your code

```
library(dplyr)

process_csv <- function(file) {
  #Load data
  data <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  #Create new data frame with date info
  data$Date <- as.POSIXlt.character(data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
  #Remove all error text to NA
  numeric_columns <- 2:ncol(data)
  for (c in numeric_columns) {
    # convert character class columns to numeric
    # NAs are coerced where data is missing (will generate warning)
    data[, c] <- as.numeric(data[, c])
    #Convert all NA values to 0
    data[is.na(data[, c]), c] <- 0
    #Converting all negative pumping rates to 0
    data[data[, c] < 0, c] <- 0
  }
  #Remove minute data and change day to date formatting
  data$Day <- as.Date(data$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
  out <- data %>%
    #Remove date column
    select(-Date) %>%
    #Group all data according to day
    group_by(Day) %>%
    #Sum all daily well data by day
    summarize_all(sum)
   return(out)
}
```

Then you can use `list.files()` to search a folder for `.csv` files:

```
folder <- "C:/path/to/your/data/"

files <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = ".csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Then you can use `lapply()` to loop through the files and apply the function to every one of them.

```
# loop over files
combined <- lapply(files, process_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```